# AngularJS recalculate "nested" functions on data change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is possibly a solution out there for this but i can't seem to find it or if i found it already i can't understand it.
I have a AngularJS app and there is the following setup:

in the view:

```
<button ng-click="data=data+1"></button>

<div>{{getValue("something")}}</div>

<div>{{getAnotherValue("anotherThing")}}</div>
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.getValue=function(param){
    return param+$scope.otherValues+$scope.data;
}
$scope.getAnotherValue=function(param){
    return param+$scope.evenOtherValues+$scope.getValue("someOtherParam");
}
```

When i click the button, the "getValue()" function is recalculated automatically but not the "getAnotherValue()". Is there a way to recalculate everything what is effected by the data change, even in this nested (or even more nested) situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are u sure `getAnotherValue()` is not updating? I set up a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t9crdqzk/) myself and it DOES updates.

In fact angular will ensure that the data bind to UI(DOM) to be correctly presented by adding $watch (watcher keeping track of the expression) to them.

Whenever there is something changed, there will be a digest cycle in which angular will go through all the watchers and check whether the data watched has changed (by recalculating it if it is a function).

For any watcher if the value has changed, angular will repeat the check process again, until all watchers reporting there is no change in the value they are watching.

If we write the process in steps:

> 1.start a digest cycle
>
> 2.ask the watchers one by one if there is any change in value
>
> 3.if any watcher reports there is a change, go back to step 1
>
> 4.if no change is reported, finish digest cycle and update UI.

However there could be exception that there are too complicated and nested watchers or any watcher loops, which will cause angular to reach the maximum number of digest cycles (default is 10). Angular will break the digest process and an exception will be thrown under this circumstance.

Comment: Well, it DOES refreshes, i did it wrong(I used ng-init in a ng-repeat, to assign the function's value to a variable and that broke it) Thank You for your reply!